# How to modify the initial orientation (and position) of a robot model

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a urdf model of a robot that I inherited. I've built a ROS package around it. When I load it into Gazebo, it ends up being below the floor place, so it "hangs" underneath the floor due to the collision detection on the feet not allowing them to fall through the floor. The rest of the robot is invisible under the floor unless I make everything transparent.

I've tried changing the origin of the parent node of the URDF model, and I've also tried passing (x, y, z, r, p, y) parameters in the args list in the launch file. Neither one seems to change the behavior in any way.

How do you specify an initial orientation and position for a model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247577/how-to-modify-the-initial-orientation-(and-position)-of-a-robot-model/) by [GlenH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28045/glenh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do so in the URDF file by specifying a world link and a joint (fixed usually) that connects world link to your base link. In the joint you control the position and orientation using the pose argument.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GlenH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28045/glenh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I thought that technique was for fixed robots? Mine is mobile.